# In php with mysql can you replace $var with :var?

Tags: php, mysql

I searched on the topics with the same name here but I didn't find anything relevant with what I have. I follow a tutorial and in a sql

```
$sql .= "WHERE event_id = :id LIMIT 1"
```

I saw that the author used :id. I assumed that should be $id. I don't know this php notation. Please, someone tell, me what is going on? Thank you.

Comment: This is called **parameter binding.** http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php There are two ways 1) named parameter `:name` or 2) positional parameters `?`

Comment: Can you post the code that comes after this line?

Comment: This is parameter binding, and is a part of [PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) - one of the preferred ways to talk to a database in PHP.

Comment: It's not, strictly speaking, a PHP notation: as far as the PHP engine is concerned, this is a normal string with no inline replacements. It's not replaced during normal string handling, but handled specially inside the PDO layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called `parameter binding`. The purpose is to prevent SQL Injections.

Example:

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Here is an good explanation:
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "UPDATE client SET password = :password, phone = :phone  WHERE id = :id;";

$query = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

$params = array(
        ':id' => $ClientId, 
        ':password' => $password,
        ':telephone' => $phone
); 

$query->execute($params)
```

It's the syntax for a prepared statement for mySQL with PDO. 
You can do:

```
$sql = "UPDATE client SET password = $password, phone = $phone  WHERE id = $ClientId;";
$query = $this->pdo->query($sql);
```

I use a class with "extends PDO" and on the construct function, I init the connection with "`$this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);`"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much lad2025 and samlev for telling me that this is called parameter binding. I found an example very easy for others that maybe will have the same question like me:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare ("INSERT INTO animal (name, category)
VALUES (:name, :cat)");
$sth->bindValue (":name", "ant");
$sth->bindValue (":cat", "insect");
$sth->execute ();
$sth->bindValue (":name", "snail");
$sth->bindValue (":cat", "gastropod");
$sth->execute ();
```

Comment: if you are binding by value - which is good then just pass the array of values directly to  `execute` rather than binding. i.e. `$sth->execute(array('name' => 'ant', 'cat' => 'insect'));` and it will do _exactly_ the same thing.